# getting error when my kendo grid has group by and I am trying to search the element

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Hi Scenario is like when I have made a grouping in my kendo grid and after that if try to search the Id(int) of the grid it throws an error also my grid is server side .
getting the error when I am trying to return the list from the controller

```js
 return isGrouping ? Json(lstofToolAction.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet) : Json(new { Data = lstofToolAction, Total = total }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

this is the error

```html
Provided expression should have string type\r\nParameter name: stringExpression filter
```

Answer (score 0):

Comparing Operator is missing in condition ,Please check your ternary operator ,Have a look below example

```
isGrouping =true ?  Json(lstofToolAction.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet) : Json(new { Data = lstofToolAction, Total = total }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Check another Example

> ```
> int first=1,second=2,result=2;
>  result = 1 ? first : second ;
> ```